# Type and Identifier are both required in a foreach statement

Tags: c#

I'm getting error in 'foreach (col in dt.Columns)' at 'in' saying that Type and Identifier are both required in a foreach statement . Below is my code. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

```
dt.TableName = "HL_IMG_TABLE";

DataColumn col = null;
foreach (col in dt.Columns)
{
   col.ColumnMapping = System.Data.MappingType.Attribute;
}
```

Comment: [foreach, in (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the iteration variable within the scope because from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with
>   a scope that extends over the embedded statement

SO, the following should be what you are looking for

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
     col.ColumnMapping = System.Data.MappingType.Attribute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the data type for the variable in the inner scope of the loop:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    col.ColumnMapping = System.Data.MappingType.Attribute;
}
```

You don't need to declare a variable of type `DataColumn` outside the scope unless you intend to use it elsewhere

Or if you want to you can use an inferred type

```
foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
{
    col.ColumnMapping = System.Data.MappingType.Attribute;
}
```

Some people love it, some people hate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
            foreach (DataColumn  col in dt.Columns)
            {
                   /* do something here*/
            }
```

Comment: @user3432638: mark one of the answers helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the type of `col`.

```
foreach (DataColumn foreach_col in dt.Columns)
{      //^
    foreach_col.ColumnMapping = System.Data.MappingType.Attribute;
}
```

This `DataColumn col = null;` is not the same as `foreach_col`.